# What is the convention for image (RGB) dimensions in Torch

Tags: torch

What is the convention for image dimensions in Torch? I'm not a torch user, but am reading some code and I need to know if Torch typically represents an RGB image as `{height, width, channels}` or as `{channels, width, height}` as I think I'm reading out of the code I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `image` package (which is the usual way to go), then it usually represents images as tensors of size `(channels, height, width)`.